# Showing tags in wordpress without link

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I would like to show a list of tags on a post but without a link on the tag. Right now I use:

```
<?php the_tags( '<li>', ', ', '</li>'); ?>
```

How do I strip the link from the tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags):

```
<?php
  $posttags = get_the_tags();
  if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      echo $tag->name . ' '; 
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Ugly as hell, but that's Wordpress style. Thanks for helping with such a basic function that needs an if and a foreach to accomplish.